# ASP Session timeout for specific session name?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Is there any way to set session timeout for just one specific session? for example I set 20 min for session A, and just want to set 10 min for session B...
I dont know if even it's possible!!!!
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

@Jay: Supposedly you can set `Session.Timeout` on a per-session basis, so I can see it working if you do something like

```
Session.Timeout = 20
Session("A") = "Value 1"

Session.Timeout = 10
Session("B") = "Value 2"
```

My experience with ASP sessions have been fairly poor though -- IIS tended to often override and ignore my script settings and sessions always timed out in the default 20 minutes. It might be a better option to go with cookies and setting their expiration time as `DateAdd("n", 20, Now())` and `DateAdd("n", 10, Now())` respectively.

Comment: The session object has no method named "Time".

Comment: @Dee: Ugh, I mean _.Timeout_; updated code sample to fix it, it was correct in the rest of my text though.

Comment: When you set the timeout for one you set it for all.  I don't believe that is the goal.

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestion. I found out that its not possible to set timeout individually for each session and any time you change the session timeout it will apply to all sessions you've created already regardless of their content. I will go with cookies. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The session object cannot have different timeouts for different values .  You will need to set/store some kind of expiration check value to accomplish this with the Session object or use the Response object cookies with a specified expiration time.

If you are referring to different users having different timeout values, then you will need to identify the user and set the timeout according to the user id.